# File not found error on ALL files in Blackberry project

Tags: blackberry, filenotfoundexception

I haven't touched any of my Blackberry projects for about 2 weeks now. Today I had to make some modifications, but when I tried to compile and run my code I got an error message like the following (this has been simplified):

```
JavaBuilder handling CoreException
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: File not found: C:\Program Files\etc etc etc\ClassName.class
```

And this error pops up for every single one of the files in my project.

I'm not a Java professional by any means, but I'm pretty sure this has something to do with my build path. What do I have to do? I did a system restore a little while back don't know if that has anything to do with this.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you are using ECLIPSE some of the files may gone; so try to update the eclipse and run your application again;

Comment: Clean and run your project....

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I cleaned the project, no change. @Alishaik, what exactly do you mean by "gone"? Also, I looked at the path of the error messages, and all the files that Eclipse claims it can't find are physically there. I don't understand this.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. For some reason alot of the folders in my project's folder were duplicated (ie: mainpackage, mainpackage(2)), so each one of my class files had a twin. Eclipse didn't tell me this, instead it just decided to say "I can't find the files" even though they were there. Not a very useful error message.

So I deleted mainpackage(2) and now it runs fine.

Thanks again for the help.